# Force download from string

Tags: php, file, download, generated

**SOLVED:** Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/16107323) comment!

I have this php page echoing some xml data, which the user should save. I want the page to automatically open the "Save as" window, since the page downloading the data is called "download.**php**" this won't start a "Save as" by it self. I read a lot of other threads here on stackoverflow by people asking the same question. None of those solves my problem. So yes, I am creating a duplicate by purpose.

This is my code:

```
$file.='<bpage>';
$file.='<title>'.$_POST["title"].'</title>';
$file.='<desc>'.$_POST["desc"].'</desc>';
$file.='<cont>'.$_POST["cont"].'</cont>';
$file.='<img>'.$_POST["img"].'</img>';
$file.='<tdata>'.$_POST["tdata"].'</tdata>';
$file.='<link>'.$_POST["link"].'</link>';
$file.='<writer>'.$_POST["writer"].'</writer>';
$file.='<date>'.$_POST["date"].'</date>';
$file.='</bpage>';

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_POST["title"].'.bpage');
echo $file;
```

I am not having any "Save as" dialog, simply the usual page, as if it ignored all my headers.
I am using Chrome and the latest version of PHP.

--
Regards Locercus

Edit:
I am using One.com for hosting. Could they possibly be blocking the header function?

Comment: possible duplicate of Related Section

Comment: You say you want the page to automatically open the "save as" window, but then say you don't want it to do that. Which is it?

Comment: Can you post a properly formatted version of your code, please?
(For instance, there is a "<br />" between your $file assignments and the headers. If it is output, then headers won't be sent to the client)

Comment: your code is not understandable...

Comment: @D.Müller The output begins after the `header()`s.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I fixed it now. Also, I simply want the save as window to appear. Sorry if I'm not clear about my purpose!

Comment: Seems like the editor screwed up my code quite a lot ... if fixed it though!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your chrome is set to auto-download files. In such case you will not see any save dialog, but the file will be downloaded to your default chrome download location.

In order to see the save dialog, do the following:

- go to Chrome Wrench Menu > Settings > Advanced Settings > Downloads and check the box which says `Ask where to save each file before downloading`

Comment: Yes, Chrome is set to auto download, but the file doesn't even download.

Comment: Can you first confirm if it downloads in other browsers (FF or IE)?

Comment: No download, no matter what browser I use. It must be something with my code or host.

Comment: It is not the code, since it works locally for me. So it has to do something with one.com. Since this does not seem to be a code issue, you will need to contact one.com customer support most probably

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out a lot! I will contact them!
Could you please add this as a answer, so I can tick it as correct?